# share var between 2 javascript files

Tags: javascript, client

I have been trying to find a way to share a variable across js files that are used by different html files (the js files are not in the same html file) but I cannot seem to find a way...

I want to create a username variable in a.js inside a.html file and then once I add it to the db on the server, move on to b.html and access username in b.js. (Ive got the all the other code working).

Ive tried session/localStorage but Atom (my text editor) is saying 'localStorage not defined', I also tried exporting/importing/requiring using emac6 but Atom is saying the same thing: 'keyword export/s not defined'. Any ideas?

//a.html :
-script src="src/a.js"- -/script-

//a.js :
var username = "john";

//b.html :
-script src="src/b.js"- -/script-

//b.js :
console.log(username);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're navigating from one page (a.html) to another (b.html), and you want to share/access data (ie username = 'john') between the two scripts that you're using on each page, then you might want to consider persisting that data to achive this.

There a many ways to do this however one simple approach would be to use the `localStorage` API as follows:

#### a.html, src/a.js

```
var username = "john";
localStorage.setItem('username', username) // Persists to browser storage
```

#### b.html,src/b.js

```
var username = localStorage.getItem('username') // Retrieves from browser storage
console.log(username);
```

Note that this is order dependant - `a.js` must be run prior to `b.js` for a value to be stored, and then logged to console.

For more information on the [localStorage API, see the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: Like I said, I have tried local storage but for some reason my atom text editor complains that it does not recognize 'localStorage'

Comment: If you prefix `localStorage` with `.window` like this : `window.localStorage` , will atom stop complaining ?

Answer (score 0):

you can also use a cookie to pass variable across any number of JavaScript.
set cookie from data creator :

```
document.cookie = "username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC";
```

then read it from others :

```
var x = document.cookie;
```